# Does "$\lnot P$" mean "$P$ is false"? Or not? ( syntax versus semantics)

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus

[ edited 11th april 2019]

Does the distinction between syntax and semantics imply that ( rigorously) the negation of P should not be read as " P is false"?

I'll try by the following comments to explain why the question is not off-topic from my point of view.

It can be argued that logical operators have a syntactic side and a semantic side.

From a syntactic point of view , the negation operator is simply ( if I am correct) a function from the set of wff to the set of wff. So the expression "~P" does not refer to the truth value of P, it only refers to  the image of the proposition symbol P under the function  " ~ "  ( that is , the function : negation).

But  from a semantic point of view, the negation operator is a function from {T,F} to {T,F}, namely the function { (T,F), (F,T) }.

So could one say that, at least from a semantic point of view, "  ~ P " could be read as " P is false" ?

Or is this reading absolutely erroneous, as not taking into account the strict distinction between syntax and semantics?

Let me add an example.

Does the formula (P --> ~P) rigorouly **mean** that " P is false" ? I think it would be more correct to say that the formula only means " not-P". So there would be a difference between " not-P" and "P is false".

Comment: It means 'not $P$'

Comment: Note that "not P" is true if and only if "P" is false, so they mean the same thing

Comment: This question is useless unless you give a source for the bizarre statement that $\lnot P$ should not be read as meaning $P$ is false.

Comment: The reading is legitimate in the context of classical logic; see [bivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence). But there are other logics, see e.g. [Intuitionsitic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) with a [specific semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation) where the above reading is not appropriate.

Comment: "So could one say that, at least from a semantic point of view, "$\lnot P$" could be read as "$P$ is false" ?" In classical logic: YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is false, then $\lnot P$ is true; if $P$ is true, then $\lnot P$ is false. It is the *negation* of $P$, whatever truth value $P$ might have, so perhaps that's where the confusion lies.

Comment: Sure, but when you assert $\neg P$ you are asserting that $\neg P$ is true, i.e., that $P$ is false.  So I would not say it's incorrect to say "$\neg P$ means $P$ is false."

Comment: That's not what the truth table of $\lnot$ says, @JairTaylor.

Comment: I suppose it's an example of the use-mention distinction.  In the context of a truth table, you are discussing $\neg P$, not asserting it.  You are just looking at the symbol $\neg P$ and evaluating its truth or falsity.  If $P$ is true, then of course the statement "P is false" is false.

Comment: @Shaun "That's not what the truth table of $\neg$ says" are you saying that it's possible for $\neg P$ to be true when $P$ *isn't* false? (It's not.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, no. Here: $$\begin{array}{c|cc} & P & \lnot P\\\hline & T & F\\ & F & T.\end{array}$$ Although, and I'm being somewhat facetious, something something something intuitionism.

Comment: @Shaun Then in what sense is Jair's comment wrong (ignoring intuitionism)? $\neg P$ means *exactly* "$P$ is false."

Comment: The statement "$P$ is false" is a [*valuation* of $P$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)), @NoahSchweber.

Comment: @Shaun Would you say that reading "~P" as " P is false" implies a confusion between syntax and semantics?

Comment: Yes, @EleonoreSaintJames :)